# Question about the input of libviso2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everybody.I am working on the project about using a single camera for navigation which will use the libviso2 to compute monocular odometry. I had read the post :http://answers.ros.org/question/46018/do-i-have-to-rectifycrop-images-before-process-them-with-viso2_ros-mono_odometry/ ,http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc and know that the input image should be rectified before feed to libviso2. What does the 'rectify' mean? Does it mean undistort image or anything else? I want to know more details about this word 'rectify' mean.Thank you everybody.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197257/question-about-the-input-of-libviso2/) by [jornwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/20775/jornwong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, *rectify* means exactly *undistort* the image. Please check the [image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc) node for more details.

---

Originally posted by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) with karma: 329 on 2014-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jornwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/20775/jornwong/) on 2014-11-13**:
Thank you for your answer,Ivan.